# Slope calculations appear to be 90 degrees off in ArcGIS 3D Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, 3d-analyst, slope

Using 10.0 I've got a raster of a fairly flat area and i'm trying to calculate the slope.  Values for elevation are accurate and I am expecting slope values no more than 5 degrees over the raster.

After running the Slope (3D Analyst) I am getting slope values of 89 - 85 degrees and can't figure out why.

According to http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Calculating_slope the slope (θ) should be from the horizontal to the grade, but it looks like its being calculated from the zenith to the grade (90-θ off of what i'm expecting).

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you warped your DEM to a projected CRS?

Comment: Nope, no warping.  DEM projection is in GC_NAD83_CSRS98.

Comment: Perhaps your DEM has degrees as units for lat/lon, and meters for height but your process believes that x, y, and z are using the same units.

Comment: @cbannon I think that might be your issue. If you're working with a DEM in a GCS, you should be converting your it to a projected CRS before running any slope calculations to ensure you have metres on the ground.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your error is a result of performing a slope calculation on a DEM that isn't in a projected Coordinate Reference System (CRS). The reason for performing a transformation/warping of your DEM is to ensure that the X (Longitude) and Y (Latitude) units correspond with your Z units (elevation in metres).

Since you mentioned that your data was in the Canadian NAD83(CSRS) projection, I'll refer you to Natural Resource Canada's [Canadian UTM Grid Reference](https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geography/topographic-information/maps/9779). This will give you an idea of the UTM projection you need depending on the Municipal Region/Province/Territory that you're trying to project.

For more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection

Answer (score 0):

Needed to convert it to a projected CRS before running any slope calculations to ensure you have metres on the ground.